# Adding and Removing custom views from custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I have created a custom `UITableViewCell`. `WTNCurrentLocationSearchResultCellTableViewCell`.

We parse data from an API into an array. Then in the `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`we check if the array is not nil and then populate the data like this:

```
WTNCurrentLocationSearchResultCellTableViewCell *searchResultCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:searchResultCellName];
if (searchResultCell == nil) {
        searchResultCell = [[WTNCurrentLocationSearchResultCellTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:searchResultCellName];
}
WTNAPIBusiness *business = self.apiBusinesses[indexPath.row];
searchResultCell.distanceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %@",(int)[business.distanceFromLocation integerValue], @"meters"];
```

**Issue**
We have a subview that is used for ratings. If you scroll to the bottom of the table and back to the top quickly the last rating view is shown on the top cells.

What I imagine is happening is that the cells are being 'reused' per the `dequeueResuable...`.

So the question is, should I clean the cell objects/outlets at the beginning of `cellForRowAtIndex`? And **more importantly** if we have a view that will only be shown if there is a specifc value else where what should we do here? I.e. if there is no rating or 0 we do not want to show the rating View. But by removing the rating view from superview it means it will never exist on cells after that?

Note: These are custom cells created in IB, with its objects/outlets linked to a custom `UITableViewCell` class. No custom init method for the class it is simply used to reference the outlets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to check the rating view whenever re-use a UITableViewCelll.

```c
WTNCurrentLocationSearchResultCellTableViewCell *searchResultCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:searchResultCellName];
if (searchResultCell == nil) {
    searchResultCell = [[WTNCurrentLocationSearchResultCellTableViewCell alloc]   initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:searchResultCellName];
}
WTNAPIBusiness *business = self.apiBusinesses[indexPath.row];
searchResultCell.distanceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %@",(int)   [business.distanceFromLocation integerValue], @"meters"];
if(SpecificValue>0){
    [searchResultCell.rateView setRate:SpecificValue];
    [searchResultCell.rateView setHidden:NO];
}else{
    [searchResultCell.rateView setHidden:YES];
}
```

Comment: This only seems to work up to a certain point. Then even if I log out on the if statement I see that the subview is set to hidden but the rating view still shows? Any thoughts?

Comment: try to give the rateView a tag. In the function above, instead of use searchResultCell.rateView, use UIView *rateView = [searchResultCell viewWithTag:2];//whatever integer you use.

Comment: Its ok, I did a bad copy on the cell name originally this is working now. Following on from this? If the view is hidden will the cell height automatically be adjusted or set to a specific value?

Comment: no, you need to set height programmatically by calling `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Answer (score 1):

In general, you want to avoid changes to the STRUCTURE of a cell during re-use. Set up each type of cell with a static set of views. Then show/hide the views as needed based on the data.

The key thing is that you want to fully configure the cell in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. If a given view will not contain data, set the contents to empty or hide the view. Don't assume that the cell will start out blank. It won't.

Don't set the views to nil. Don't set the (string) contents to nil. instead, either set the string contents to an empty string: @"", or set the view to `hidden=YES`.

If the code outlined by Hao above doesn't work then there is something wrong.

It sounds like you're confused. I would suggest keeping it simple and not using prepareForReuse or didEndDisplayingCell. Do all the work in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: You are 100% correct, in fact Hao was right. I have similar cell names and copied the incorrect one so the hidden wasn't working but is now. Following on from this? If the view is hidden will the cell height automatically be adjusted or set to a specific value?

Comment: @StuartM You need to return the desired height in tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: based on whether it will show the rating view or not.

Answer (score 0):

Table view cells can be reset when any of the following methods are invoked:

- `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` (`UITableViewDataSource`) - The data source may reset a cell before reuse.
- `prepareForReuse` (`UITableViewCell`) - The cell may reset itself before reuse.
- `tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` (`UITableViewDelegate`) - The delegate may reset content which must be cleared *as soon as the cell is no longer visible*.

Comment: Typically in the `prepareForReuse` would you set the label to nil or the text. I.e. `self.mainLabel = nil` OR `self.mainLabel.text = nil`. Also how do you suggest the second part to the question, more importantly part. How should we handle removing the view for a subview that does not need to show, and how to ensure it exists/available for the next cell?

Comment: @StuartM Your custom UITableViewCell should be responsible for adding/removing subviews.  For example, if you set a property on the cell such as `showsRating` to YES, the cell class should add a rating view to its contentView if it does not already exist.

Comment: Could you provide an example/link on how to do this please? Should I just create a public property for the showsRating and then on the setter of that run a private method to add/remove the view as required?